# Атлетичный и атлетический (-ный, -ский)

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, окончания

В чём разница между этими двумя словами? (В чём разница в этих двух словах?) Порой русский язык убивает. 
Вот есть у нас слова «атлетичный» и «атлетический», значат вроде одно и то же, но ведь не зря же они имеют разные окончания? И вот объясните мне, пожалуйста, эту разницу в выражениях «атлетичное телосложение» и «атлетическое телосложение». 
На прямой вопрос гуглу, кстати, он выбивает только словари синонимов… а как понять, как использовать данные прилагательные — хоть убей, не могу. 
Умоляю, разъясните!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вот есть у нас слова «атлетичный» и «атлетический», значат вроде одно
>   и то же, но ведь не зря же они имеют разные окончания?

Во-первых, не окончания, а суффиксы. Во-вторых, бывает и так, что именно "зря". 
Но это не наш случай. Здесь мы имеем дело с паронимами, то есть похожими словами, являющимися  частичными синонимами.

> «атлетичное телосложение» и «атлетическое телосложение»

В данном примере семантической разницы я не вижу, только стилистическую - и то весьма слабую. Как научный термин чаще используется вариант "атлетичное телосложение", в разговорной речи чаще - "атлетическое".

Словари несколько расходятся в формулировках, но если взять БТС Кузнецова, то "атлетический" имеет два значение, в одном из которых является синонимом "атлетичный", а во втором с ним совсем не совпадает.

> АТЛЕТИЧЕСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. к Атлетика и Атлетизм. А-ие упражнения.
>   А-ая гимнастика (культуризм). 2. Свойственный атлету; такой, как у
>   атлета. А-ое телосложение. А-ая фигура. <Атлетически, нареч. (2 зн.).
>   А. сложенный юноша. А. крепок.
>
> АТЛЕТИЧНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. =Атлетический (2 зн.).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87*&all=x

Итак, человек (фигура) -  атлетический и атлетичный. Гимнастика - только атлетическая.

Answer (score 0):

Да, словари синонимов обычно органичиваются составлением последовательности слов, которые в неназванных контекстах мало чем отличаются. Для пары "**атлетичный - атлетический**" можно, тем не менее, найти различие в употреблении: "атлетическое сложение" - да, и в любом контексте. Но попробуйте в выражении "**атлетичный юноша, спортсмен**" заменить эпитет "**атлетичный**" на "*атлетический*" - не выйдет. Следовательно, *различие в употреблении* существует. Я бы не назвал выражение "атлетичное сложение" (в моём восприятии: "во многом /или в чём-то/ как у  атлета") *полным* синонимом выражения "атлетическое сложение" (такое, как у атлета).

Comment: *Но попробуйте в выражении "атлетичный юноша, спортсмен" заменить эпитет "атлетичный" на "атлетический" - не выйдет.* - а у меня прекрасно выходит. И у многих авторов - тоже. *И по странному стечению обстоятельств, на террасу как раз поднялся атлетический юноша Юра Броммель, по кличке – ну, догадайтесь – правильно – Бром.* (В.Аксенов, "Кесарево сечение")

Comment: А я не назвал бы такой выбор слова авторской удачей. Конкретно это произведение писалось после многих лет, проведенных автором в эмиграции - это всегда влияет на язык. А как вам "атлетический спортсмен"?